# How to resume/bring back to foreground X-session running in the background?

Tags: 12.10, xorg

I have started an X session on tty1 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> by :

```
startx -- :1
```

Now after I went to my 'standard' X session to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F7</kbd> 
 and then back to tty1 and get the prompt instead of X session.

How can I recover/bring back my X session that I started ? And second thing about that, I tried killing process that I started with `startx` so I removed `/tmp/.X1-lock` and now I get this when I try to `startx`-

```
[205846.354] _XSERVTransSocketINETCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
[205846.354] _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
[205846.354] 
Fatal server error:
[205846.354] Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running
[205846.355] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[205846.355] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
[205846.356] (EE) 
[205846.356] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: Is your second X session on ctrl-alt-F8 ?

Comment: Surprisingly it is o.O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X sessions run on virtual terminals, F7-F12

When you start a new X session, although you might call it "1" or "2" or what not, they start on the next available vitrutual terminal.

Try locating your second X session on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F8</kbd>